# OnDemandResource and new version App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, on-demand-resources

I ran into the problem of `OnDemandResource`:

1) I download from `TestFlight` the old version App... App downloads `OnDemandResource` and everything works fine.

2) I upload a new version App in which I add new resources, and install it as an update on the old version. And when the new version App is running, not download of new `OnDemandResource`, App believes that all resources are downloaded.

How to fix it?

First start old version:

```
NSSet *tags = [NSSet setWithObjects: @"PACK_1", @"PACK_2", nil];
NSBundleResourceRequest *resourceRequest = [[NSBundleResourceRequest alloc] initWithTags:tags];
resourceRequest.loadingPriority = 1.0;
[resourceRequest conditionallyBeginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL resourcesAvailable) {
    if (resourcesAvailable) {
    } else {

        // Download PACK_1 and PACK_2

        [resourceRequest beginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError * __nullable error) {
            if(!error){
            } else {

                // Run App
            }
        }];
    }
}];
```

First start new version (updated old version, add new PACK_3):

```
NSSet *tags = [NSSet setWithObjects: @"PACK_1", @"PACK_2", @"PACK_3", nil];
NSBundleResourceRequest *resourceRequest = [[NSBundleResourceRequest alloc] initWithTags:tags];
resourceRequest.loadingPriority = 1.0;
[resourceRequest conditionallyBeginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL resourcesAvailable) {

    // Check PACK_1, PACK_2 and PACK_3 and resourcesAvailable = true, but PACK_3 not download

    if (resourcesAvailable) {

        // Run App

    } else {

        // Will not start to download PACK_3

        [resourceRequest beginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError * __nullable error) {
            if(!error){
            } else {
            }
        }];
    }
}];
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, but did you manage to solve this?